# Admin not able to restore deleted pages

Tags: sitecore-client, security

I am facing issue while restoring deleted pages in sitecore. The page which is deleted by author was not able to restore by admin.Please refer below screenshot for error while restore...
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any error in logs?

Comment: Unless there is something in the logs files I don't think that is SXA related.

Comment: Can you roll back to a backup before the items got deleted in the short term? Also, if there are any logs please share as @MarekMusielak asked. Best. jb